# Passing a variable into a constructor

Tags: c#, syntax, signalr

What is the difference (and why would you use this syntax) in passing a variable into a function?

```
return _acks.GetOrAdd(id, new AckInfo()).Tcs.Task;

return _acks.GetOrAdd(id, _ => new AckInfo()).Tcs.Task;

return _acks.GetOrAdd(id, (_) => new AckInfo()).Tcs.Task;
```

What is the best practice / use case around this?

[Here is the code in context](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Infrastructure/AckHandler.cs)

Line 41

Answer (score 4):

I wrote that code so I can answer :). The second and third are the same but the difference between the first is that you're allocating a new AckInfo everytime vs creating a delegate that will be run if need be. It's delaying the allocation of the AckInfo until the very last minute.

Answer (score 0):

The last two are the same. They are an empty `Action` with no parameters. The underscore signifies a placeholder for nothingness.

The first one wouldn't compile.. assuming the method expected an `Action`. Otherwise, it would, if there was an overload.

So, the answer is there is no best practice. They are the same.. or they are used for a specific purpose (`Action` vs no `Action`).

I suggest you [have a read up on what Delegates are in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Specifically, [what the Action delegate is useful for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.action%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: It is also possible that the first one will be the same as the last two, if implicit conversion is available to turn the object into an Action.